# how can i open P-CAD file (.pcb, .sch extension)?

Tags: c#, cad

which library i can use that read p-cad files? 
There is a some API?
The point is - i want to read all parts of schema (.sch) and create specification in excel format.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do in these cases is search for `format of .sch files` or `format of .pcb files`.

Read each of those descriptions, skip the crap / sales pitch stuff and find **EAGLE file formats**

http://www.element14.com/community/thread/14344/l/eagle-file-formats?displayFullThread=true

This should be a good start